# Can the results for a try/catch for sp_MSforeachdb be put in a temp table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Can the results for a try/catch for sp_MSforeachdb be put in a temp table?

- I'm trying to drop a user from all databases on an instance and I would like the results of the catch, or results of another method to show as the following picture.
- I'm not sure how or if it's possible to manipulate the spMSforeachdb proc to have a result as follows:

**Desired Result:**

[image]

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE ? select''?'';  
begin try
  drop user [username]  
  print ''did drop at ?''
end try
begin catch
  select Error_Message()
  print ''did not drop at ?'' 
end catch
'
GO
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't use that procedure. It is undocumented and even better is that it will sometimes skip databases and nobody seems to know why. A much better alternative can be found [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange!  Can Arron's code be used to give an output similar to the desired result picture?  Is it possible?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I haven't tried anything like that to be honest. I would say give it a shot and see how it works. Or you could always just roll with a diy cursor. I mean needing to do something to every database is one of those rare times where a cursor is actually the right tool for the job.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks!